# Seadragon Deep Zoom: DZI of different size render issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas, seadragon

Using seadragon to display DZI images. But I have DZI are of different sizes.
I am using following code do that:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dziurl = '<%=ViewData["url"]%>';
        viewer = new Seadragon.Viewer("container");
        viewer.openDzi(dziurl, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Image xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008" Format="jpg" Overlap="2" TileSize="265" > <Size Height="8500" Width="12600"/> </Image>');
    });
```

Issue arise when DZI file is different size(Height,Width) comes. Seadragon renders them  but for large image, their edges got cluttered.
If I increase Height and Width inside <Size> tag in javascript then small images got repeated . Below is the screenshot.
[image]

How to resolve..any suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

On the openDzi line, you should just pass in the DZI URL and not the XML data. That should sort it out. On the other hand, if the XML is on another server and you can't access it directly, you'll need to come up with some strategy for getting the correct XML data. Let me know if you need information on that.

By the way, are you aware of the new version of Seadragon Ajax? It's now at:

http://openseadragon.github.io/